# Weekly reminder message that repeats until user performs action

Tags: excel, vba

I developed an add-in to purge old project files weekly.

I would like my reminder form to pop up on a user's PC once a day (upon loading the add-in / opening up Excel) until they run the purge sub. After running a purge the reminder should only pop back up a week later.

I thought of creating a log file of reminders and testing the current date/time to it, but that seems like a project of its own.

Any ideas on a good approach / example code?

Comment: If the addin is stored locally - ie each user has their own copy then just store the date of last reminder inside the add in. An Excel xlam file has it's own, invisible worksheet so you can store data there using ThisWorksheet.Worksheets(1).Range("a1") and then check that against the current date. If you have one add in for everyone then you'll need to store their login and date. (You can get their log in using ENVIRON)

Comment: Thanks. That could work. I didn't know that the sheet can be used. Let me try that and revert back. I appreciate your help, thank you.

Comment: You could use `CustomDocumentProperties` to set the date and check `.Add "LastRefresh", False, msoPropertyTypeDate, Date`

Comment: Thank you @HarassedDad. Your solution worked perfectly. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So I have managed to do this using @HarassedDad 's solution (thank you)

```
Sub checkReminder()
Dim dateLastPurge, dateLastReminder As Date

dateLastPurge = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value
dateLastReminder = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A2").Value

If ((Date - dateLastPurge) > 6) And ((Date - dateLastReminder) > 0) Then
    MsgBox "Please note that you have not purged your files in the last 7 days. A purge is overdue.", vbExclamation, "Purge Overdue"
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A2").Value = Date
    Main.Show
End If
End Sub
```